# Creating custom emoji iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I understand there are 1127 apps about custom emoji keyboard on App Store. Since I wish to not put the exact app idea here, I will give an example.

If I wish to build a custom keyboard with custom emojis, is it actually possible? I don't only mean if that is possible technically. I'm also asking if Apple actually allow it?

I tried doing my research and some sites say, they only allow emojis that are built into the phone and not custom.

Again, I don't want to make a chat app where my emojis will be useable. I want to make a keyboard app and if both users have the keyboard, the emojis will work perfectly. The keyboard should be useable throughout iOS environment.

Is this possible and does Apple allow it?

If yes, I would really appreciate some starting point guidelines since I'm a VERY new to iOS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not possible:The problem which will arise is that you would have to add your emoji by sending a request to http://unicode.org/consortium/consort.html.
This is the institute will accept/reject new emojis supported by ios and andriod.
Actually the emojis are unicode characters that are decoded by os.So if you try to add a unicode by yourself that will not be decoded by os.

Your unicode characters can be decoded if you use them in an app not in keyboard extension.Than your app can decode it.e.g say {186abjd} = {your image} than for decoding you can check the string for {186abjd} if that text is found replace it by your image.Remember that this can't be an emoji as emoji are text and you cannot use text.